# Show that the norm is continuous in the following sense:

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $(E,||.||)$ be a normed space. Suppose
$(x_n) \subseteq E$ converges and $x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$. Then $||x|| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||x_n||$. I tried to use the triangle inequality because I think it can applied in a certain form here, but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $\bigl| \|x_n\|-\|x\| \bigr| \le \|x_n - x\| < \varepsilon$ for big enough $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the triangle inequality, you can prove the so-called reverse triangle inequality:
$$\forall (x,y)\in E^2,\ |\Vert x\Vert - \Vert y\Vert|\leqslant \Vert x+y\Vert$$
Replacing $y$ with $-y$, you get that the norm is Lipschitz continuous, hence continuous on $E$.

Comment: What is Lipschitz continuous? Is there a way of doing it without that?

Comment: $f\colon E\to F$ ($F$ is also a normed space) is Lipschitz continuous on $E$ if there exists a number $k>0$ such that $\Vert f(x)-f(y)\Vert\leqslant k\Vert x-y\Vert$ for all $(x,y)$ in $E^2$. You can easily verify that such a function is continuous using the basic $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity (take $\delta=\varepsilon/k$). In your case, $f=\Vert .\Vert$ , $F=\mathbb{R}$ and $k=1$: we have $|\Vert x\Vert-\Vert y\Vert|\leqslant \Vert x-y\Vert$ for all $(x,y)$ in $E^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have for all $x,y$:

$$\big\vert \vert\vert x\vert\vert-\vert\vert y\vert\vert\big\vert\leqslant \vert\vert x-y\vert\vert.$$

So $\vert\vert.\vert\vert$ is $1$-Lipschitz continuous.

So $\vert\vert.\vert\vert$ is continuous.

So for all sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim x_n=x$:

$$\lim \vert\vert x_n\vert\vert=\vert\vert x\vert\vert.$$

Comment: What is 1-Lipschitz continuous? Is there a way of doing it without that?